# Is it possible to browse favorite questions by tag?

Tags: support, tags, bookmarks, search

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to browse my favorite questions by tags (similar to how we browse normal questions), but I don't know exactly how I can do this.

Does anyone know how can I do that? Or is such functionality not currently available for favorite questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy to do, if you put two and two together:

1. You can search/filter by tag by typing the name of the tag in brackets, and
2. You can search in your favorited questions using the `infavorites` operator.

So [the following search queue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infavorites%3A2387673+%5Bpython%5D) will return all of your favorited questions with the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag:

```
[python] infavorites:1
```

Comment: or even better `infavorites:mine`.

Comment: @hims056: thanks for pointing that out. I am about to ask what does `:1` mean!

Comment: @keelar - For more details have a look at *Advanced Search Tips* situated at the right side in this search page.

Comment: Ah, right. Good point, @hims. `1 == TRUE` in my mind, so it seemed obvious what it was doing. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray: `:1` is not clear to me as a new user especially when I found my submitted search will be replaced by something like `[java] infavorites:2387673` ...

Comment: @keelar Yes, `2387673` is your unique user ID. You'll see it in the URL when you visit your profile page. I understand that the team is working on an advanced search page to add to the Help Center. That should help make this obscure syntax more discoverable.

Comment: +1 didn't know "infavorites:1" is a shorthand to "infavorites:mine", now I can type 3 less characters.